# SharedPreferences.for RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: java, android, radio-button

How to use shared preferences for radio button in radio group. I have two buttons (next and previous).  I want to check the user selected option when user goes to next and came to previous again that time

```java
 radioGroup = findViewById( R.id.radioGroup );
       radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
               ToggleableRadioButton radioButton = (ToggleableRadioButton) group. findViewById(checkedId);
               int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
               SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
               editor.putInt("check", checkedIndex);
               editor.apply();
           }
       } );




 private void Update(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("check", 0);
        System.out.println("savedRadioIndex is "+savedRadioIndex);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
       ToggleableRadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (ToggleableRadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);//error on this line


    }
```

/////log cat ,,,,error of my code

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.quiz.ToggleableRadioButton.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

layout///////////// this is layou in which RadioGroup and radio button shows

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <com.example.quiz.ToggleableRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 1"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />

            <com.example.quiz.ToggleableRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 2"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />

            <com.example.quiz.ToggleableRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 3"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />

            <com.example.quiz.ToggleableRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 4"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: are you sure `R.id.radioGroup` exists in the layout of this fragment/activity

Comment: yes i am sure 100%

Comment: can you share the layout in which radio group is

Comment: ok i edited please check

Comment: i think the problem is with custom `ToggleableRadioButton` otherwise everything looks fine to me , can you verify by using normal `RadioButton` once

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In layout file

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton2" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

In activity

```
String radiovalue=null; //globally declared

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case R.id.radioButton:
                       radiovalue= R1.getText().toString();//R1 is radiobutton1
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2:
                         radiovalue= R2.getText().toString();//R2 is radiobutton2
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

After that put the radiovalue in  shared preferences.
When you call the  shared preferences value just check value and make radiobutton enabled according to it.

Comment: and i already done it with radioButton but same error come

Comment: on previous button click

Comment: I think there is problem in your app flow.I don't get why you call update method on previous button.It would be more helpful if you can provide full activity code.

Comment: i just want when i click previous button it show previous checked option from 4 option which i selected ,,, if you have any other way to do this please tell me
(it is a quiz app in which user select answer of question asked )

Comment: Taking just 2 activity.Both have same layout.So on next button you should start intent for next activity and create shared preferences for current activity.when you reach on 2nd activity,On previous button just start intent for first activity and in 1st activity's on create method call those created shared preferences (put them in try catch block) .